# Element of Matrix is the Memory addres and not the value of element

Tags: java, math, matrix

I have a matrix homework. When I run the program, in the console It always returns by the memory address and not by the values.
I am European, I used the German locale. I've thought that maybe the localization is the problem, so I've changed to US, but It doesn't solves my problem.

In console:

```
[[D@459189e1, [D@55f33675]
[[D@527c6768, [D@65690726]
```

Here my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Inverse2x2Matrix {

    public static double[][] inverse2x2Matrix(double[][] A) {
        double det = A[0][0] * A[1][1] - A[0][1] * A[1][0];
        double m00 = -1 * A[1][1] / det;
        double m01 = A[0][1] / det;
        double m10 = A[1][0] / det;
        double m11 = -1 * A[0][0] / det;
        double[][] B = { { m00, m01 }, { m10, m11 } };
        return B;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

    System.out.println("Enter a, b, c, d: 0");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input=sc.next();
    sc.close();

    double[][] A = new double[2][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            A[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(input);
        }
    }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inverse2x2Matrix(A)));
    }
        double[][] C = {{1.0,2.0},{3.0,4.0}};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(C));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inverse2x2Matrix(C)));

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Arrays.deepToString`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) to pretty-print the contents of an array recursively. Else, every element of the array is printed using its `toString` method, which indeed prints its type followed by its hashCode.

Answer (score 2):

`A` is array of array, so when you type `Arrays.toString(A)` it takes every inner array of `A` and call `toString` on it, which returns this address-like representation. You need to iterate through `A` manually:

```
for (double[] ar : A) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ar));
}
```

Or write helper method:

```
private static void printArray(double[][] ar) {
    for (double[] inner : ar) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(inner));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

JB Nizet's advice is much better.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is explain why I had problem :)